# $n+n \rightarrow n+n$ scattering through photon interaction (QED Process)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, photons, standard-model, quantum-electrodynamics, neutrons

If I think about the quark level process then, two u quarks can scatter through photon exchange via QED interaction by following tree-level process

[image: Tree Level Feynmanb Diagram for QED 2 to 2 scattering interaction process].

This is happening because u quark is electrically charged particle, which has a non-trivial charge under $\mathcal{u}(1)_{em}$, and then 2 d spectator quarks confined with u quark can form a hadronic bound state of the neutron.

On the other hand, if we think about the hadron level process, then as the neutron is an electric charge-neutral particle, it should not participate in QED interactions. Then the neutron should not be scattered through photon exchange. ***Then where is the ambiguity between my two arguments about quark level and hadron level thinking?***

Comment: You've basically come to the conclusion that the neutron isn't a fundamental particle, and the neutron does have a nonzero magnetic moment because of its constituents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paradox refers to low energies, where the neutron can be modeled as an elementary particle with zero electric charge. To resolve the paradox, remember that the neutron has a [nonzero magnetic dipole moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_magnetic_moment). One observable effect of the neutron's magnetic dipole moment — at energies where the neutron can be treated as an elementary particle — is nicely reviewed in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/322017) by ACuriousMind. Regarding how much the magnetic dipole moment affects scattering, reference 1 says this on page 2:

> The magnitude of the cross-section of the neutron magnetic scattering is similar to the cross-section of nuclear scattering by short-range nuclear forces.

In that paper, neutrons are used to probe the structure of condensed matter. That's a little different than pure neutron-neutron scattering, but it still illustrates the fact that the neutron's nonzero magnetic moment can have a non-negligible effect on scattering in general. Note that direct measurements of isolated neutron-neutron scattering are difficult: according to reference 2, direct measurements had still not yet been done as of 2005. For an update, see reference 3. But theoretically, the QED-mediated interaction does contribute, even at low energies where the neutron can be treated as an elementary particle. This resolves the paradox.

I said that the paradox only refers to low energies because at high enough energies, treating the neutron as an elementary particle is clearly not a good approximation any more: scattering — including QED-mediated scattering — can produce resonances or even break the neutron apart (into other hadrons, because quarks are confined).

---

References:

1. Zaliznyak and Lee (2004), *Magnetic neutron scattering* (https://www.bnl.gov/isd/documents/27263.pdf)
2. Mitchell *et al* (2005), *A Direct Measurement of the Neutron-Neutron Scattering Length* (https://www.scielo.br/j/bjp/a/kQFQgdY8CdC8wfg9F7dJXJt/?lang=en)
3. Stephenson *et al* (2012), *Experiment on direct nn scattering — The radiation-induced outgassing complication* (https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2012NuPhA.895...33S/abstract)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

My sense is you know that the neutron is a composite particle of size 0.8 fm, and wonder how a tree photon interaction by anything charged inside the "upper" *n* (it's actually simpler to think of e-n scattering)  can "see" the quarks of the lower *n*, but fail to "see" the whole as a neutral object.

The point is that for energies *much lower* than 1/(0.8fm) you see the total, aggregate charge of the *n*, null, because you must *add* the lowest-order tree diagrams you wrote,  in this case the photon coupling to the u, plus to the d, plus to the other d valence quark. The resulting coupling, *if you cannot resolve the difference among these three valence quarks*, is just (2/3-1/3-1/3)=0! (This is something like the chiral bag model.)

The comments and the other answer remind you that if, at slightly higher energies, comparable to the inverse Compton wavelength of the *n*, you can *resolve* the three valence quarks, (they have a peculiar spin structure, where they contribute unequally), you can "see" their magnetic effects and the neutral *n* has a nontrivial [magnetic moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_magnetic_moment#The_nature_of_the_neutron%27s_magnetic_moment), about -2/3 that of the charged proton! (This is because magnetism is shorter-ranged than electric forces.)

In fact, as you increase your scattering energy to come close to the above-mentioned radius of the *n*, you start seeing inhomogeneities in the charge distribution inside this neutral particle!  The [charge-radius-squared of the neutron is](https://doi.org/10.1038/s41467-021-22028-z) -0.1 fm², which, of course, means the negatively-charged *d* quarks are radially distributed "further out" in the neutron compared to the *u* quark", so to speak. The corresponding quantity for the proton is 0.6 fm². So for such higher energies, you indeed have a mismatch between the hadron and quark pictures: that's *why* people bother with the latter...

Comment: Thanks sir, thank you so much!!

Comment: Glad it makes sense.